# Excel formula Comparing two arrays

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a table (xTable, 3 columns:Name, Start, Stop). On another sheet I have a calendar I am trying to make. The A1 row are dates. The A1 column are names.

I am trying to compare the start date in my xTable to the date in my A1 row. If the date is found, look at first column of the xTable, if it equals the name of the person in A1 colum, return true, if not, return false.

Something like: `=INDEX($B$2:$AF$14,ROW(A2)-1,MATCH($B$16,$B$1:$AF$1,0))="x"`

But for the life of me, i cannot get it to work...I was thinking maybe because I have about 400 rows of data, but I just am not sure. Any help is appreciated! Also, if you know of a vba solution, I could always use that..but I prefer try to keep it in formulas. But beggars should not be choosy ;)

```
     | 01 | 02 | 03 | 04 | 05 | 06 | 07 | 08 | 09 | 10 | 11 | 12 |etc---> 
Name1|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
Name2|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
Name3|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
Name4|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
Name5|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
Name6|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
Name7|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
Name8|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|
Name9|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|____|


Name |Start|Stop |
Name1| 3   |  6  |
Name1| 1   |  12 |
Name7| 10  |  10 |
Name3| 21  |  30 |
Name1| 9   |  12 |
Name9| 7   |  15 |
Name9| 1   |  3  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to populate the calendar with the start dates from xTable with `TRUE` when found and with `FALSE` otherwise?

You can use this formula in cell B2 and fill it right and down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A$13:$A$19,$A2,$B$13:$B$19,B$1*1)=0,FALSE,TRUE)
```

I'm using `B$1*1` just in case you have the dates stored as number in row A1. Otherwise, if they are stored as date but formatted as `dd` (or equivalent), use `DAY(B$1)` instead.

The formula will count the number of occurrences of a row with the corresponding name and start date of table xTable using `COUNTIFS`. If none are found, it will return 0, which yields to `FALSE`.

Comment: Hey Jerry, much love and appreciation! Both the table and the row are using real dates, so I took the DAY() out and it works like a champ. Now I will work on adding the end date so it can fill the spots between the start and end date. Again...really really appreciate you sharing your knowledge. I banged my head on the wall for about 4 18 hour days.

Comment: @DavidMassey Good luck with combining both! :)